# How to create a slack notification channel in Google Cloud Platform with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create a slack notification channel in GCP with terraform. I am able to create a channel with the code below, but it's missing "Team" and "Owner" attributes.

```
resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "default" {
  display_name = "Test Slack Channel"
  type         = "slack"
  enabled      = "true"
  labels = {
    "channel_name" = "#testing"
    "auth_token"   = "<my_slack_app_token>"
  }
}
```

The first channel in the screenshot below was created via GUI and works fine. The second channel was created via terraform and is unable to send notificaitons:
[image: Slack channels]

[Terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/monitoring_notification_channel) does not mention these attributes, I have tried defining them in *labels* right after *channel_name*:

```
labels = {
  "channel_name" = "#testing"
  "team"         = "<my_team>"
  "owner"        = "google_cloud_monitoring"
  "auth_token"   = "<my_slack_app_token>"
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Error creating NotificationChannel: googleapi: Error 400: Field "notification_channel.labels['owner']" is not allowed; labels must conform to the channel type's descriptor; permissible label keys for "slack" are: {"auth_token", "channel_name"}
```

Apparently, only *channel_name* and *auth_token* are valid labels.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi @Miro K,

I would like to figure out better what you want to do with "Team" and "Owner" attributes. Can you please share the code where you are using those attributes? Which is the error shows?

Comment: Hi @MarlenMonroy, I have added an example code of "team" and "owner" labels as I have tried using them, the error below is what I got.

Comment: Hi @MiroK, feel free to enrich the question with a screenshot of the GUI that shows that the fields `team` and `owner` should be valid for the resource type of `google_monitoring_notification_channel`.

Comment: Hi, I replicated your scenario and I notice the same performance as you mention, but unfortunately values `owner` and `team` are not within Google API, so the best channel in this case is to open a case in terraform directly

Comment: Any updates on this @MiroK? I'm facing the same issue as of now and this is literally the only post on the web I can find which mentions the same exact issue that I'm having.

Comment: @Meuko the team and owner options are missing from the GCP API, I have opened an issue ( https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184556867?pli=1 ) but it remains unresolved.

Comment: I bumped it, hope to see this fixed soon. Thanks for opening the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Slack needs the `sensitive_lables` option for tokens. There is an example in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_notification_channel#example-usage---notification-channel-sensitive)

```
resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "default" {
  display_name = "Test Slack Channel"
  type         = "slack"
  labels = {
    "channel_name" = "#foobar"
  }
  sensitive_labels {
    auth_token = "...."
  }
}
```